# Issues in loading MNIST dataset while running on the command prompt, Windows 10

Tags: python, pytorch, mnist, torchvision

[python file execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQZQw.png)

I am trying to run a python file from my windows command prompt which uses the MNIST dataset using a machine learning algorithm. The dataset is not getting loaded when I run python file_name.py. See the attached screenshot. But, when I execute the same file on my mac or the google colab, its working perfectly fine.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

def main():
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])
    train_dataset = datasets.MNIST('./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    train_loader_server = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

I have tried the above code snippet but the dataset is not loading.